# Программа по подсчету банковских процентов

Tags: java, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

```
public class BankProcents {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double vklad = 1000;
        double procent = 0.02;

        for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++) {
            vklad += vklad * procent;
            System.out.println("За " + year + " год, на вашем счету появилась " + vklad + " сумма долларов");
        }
    }
}
```

Увидел вот такую программку по подсчету банковских процентов, не могу понять почему если мы вычисляем 2% годовых то мы пишем 0.02, а не 0.2?

Comment: нельзя деньги считать в double

Comment: 0.2 * 100 == 20

Comment: 0.02 * 100 == 2

Comment: Потому что 2% это две сотых, а не две десятых :рукалицо:

Comment: @Эникейщик да сам себя понял, какой вопрос :рукалицо:))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя деньги считать в `double`, это связано с особенностями точности представления числа ([IEEE754](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)), хочу заметить эту ошибку можно встретить во многих реальных системах в продакшене.

Считайте в `long` или `BigInteger` копейки или любые доли копеек, в зависимости от необходимой точности.

По вопросу:

`100% == 1`

`100%/50 == 1/50`

`2% == 0.02`

---

```
public class BankPercents {

    // дробная часть, необходимо увеличить для повышения точности
    static BigInteger multiplier = new BigInteger("1000");

    // 2%
    static BigInteger divider = new BigInteger("50"); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BigInteger deposit = new BigInteger("100000").multiply(multiplier); // 1000.00 $

        for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++) {
            deposit = deposit.add(deposit.divide(divider));
            log(year, deposit);
        }
    }

    public static void log(int year, BigInteger deposit) {
        BigInteger amount = deposit.divide(multiplier);
        System.out.println("За " + year + " год, на вашем счету появилась " + amount + " сумма центов");
    }
}
```

> `За 1 год, на вашем счету появилась 102000 сумма центов`
>
> `За 2 год, на вашем счету появилась 104040 сумма центов`
>
> `За 3 год, на вашем счету появилась 106120 сумма центов`
>
> `За 4 год, на вашем счету появилась 108243 сумма центов`
>
> `За 5 год, на вашем счету появилась 110408 сумма центов`

---

Вот вариант с `long`

```
public class BankPercents {

    // дробная часть, необходимо увеличить для повышения точности
    static long multiplier = 1000;

    // 2%
    static long divider = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long deposit = 100000 * multiplier; // 1000.00 $

        for (int year = 1; year <= 5; year++) {
            deposit += deposit/divider;
            log(year, deposit);
        }
    }

    public static void log(int year, long deposit) {
        long amount = deposit/multiplier;
        System.out.println("За " + year + " год, на вашем счету появилась " + amount + " сумма центов");
    }
}
```

Comment: А можете добавить кусочек кода отредактировав мой, чтобы я понимал как правильно считать?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван c long естественно все проще, привел сложный вариант, попробуйте убрать множитель(1000) чтобы увидеть как изменится значение на счету

Comment: Это отличный ответ, но на какой-то другой вопрос, а не на заданный. Чтобы он не пропал и легко находился - лучше задайте свой вопрос и перенесите этот ответ туда.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо за совет, я попробую =)

Comment: @Kromster или попросить автора отредактировать вопрос?)

Comment: Зачем диктовать автору писать то в чем он не разбирается? (и м/б даже не хочет). Лучше задайте новый. Самоответы тут приветствуются, а с правками я с радостью помогу.